# Dynamodb table structure - which one of these two better support a hierarchical data relationship?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb

The data structure in question is a simplified version of the problem I am aiming to solve. The primary focus of this question is to address which of the two ways is better suited to address this kind of data structure. The problem is to help illustrated the underlying data structure. Please restraint from suggestions such as "why don't you change your workflow this way?".

**Problem**:

Currently for each invoice, there is an associated approval. An approver needs to inspect the invoice and stamp their approvals. There is a one-to-one relationship between the invoice and the approval.

In my existing dynamodb table (**APPROVAL**), it has the following fields

| field | description |
| --- | --- |
| invoice number |  |
| approval number |  |
| approval status |  |

Now I want to expand to support an approval per line-item in an invoice. There will be a 1-to-N relationship between the invoice and approvals. Also a 1-to-N invoice level approval and line-item level approval.

However in many cases, an invoice does not require per line-item approval (PLA). An invoice level approval (IA) is sufficient.

For many reasons I want to maintain the existing workflows that is already working with the invoice level approval. For example, if I query an invoice's approval status of an IA, it will be a simple flag in the record itself. But if it is a PLA, an approval is only granted if all PLA are also approved (so a query of all associated PLAs is necessary).

In particular, the ability to delete the ILA quickly without waiting for the removal of all the associated approval is a plus.

So in my dymanodb design, I can either:

1. Reuse the original table and add new columns

| field | description |
| --- | --- |
| invoice number |  |
| line number | NEW: The number of line item in the invoice, 1-indexed, so '0' can be used to indicate it is the parent approval |
| approval number |  |
| approval status |  |

Or,

2. Introduce a new line item table

**APPROVAL**

| field | description |
| --- | --- |
| invoice number |  |
| approval number | partition key |
| approval status |  |
| require line item approval | NEW: indicate if the parent is a IA or PLA |

**SUBAPPROVAL**

| field | description |
| --- | --- |
| parent approval number | link back to the approval in the master table; partition key. |
| line number | The number of line item in the invoice, 1-indexed |
| approval status |  |

In dynamodb, is there any distinct advantage/disadvantage in capturing the 1:N in either one of approach? My main concern are performance and read/write capacity.

I prefer the 2nd approach (adding new table) because, from a design point of view, it is more future proof: If someone want to throw in another approval model, I don't have to shoehorn it into the same table.,

Comment: Can you maybe list out the access patterns? I can guess a few from the description, but it would help if you list them out, e.g. "Get invoice by id", "Get all unapproved invoices"

Comment: What are the PK and SK of the existing table? Is changing what's in the PK and SK a possibility? Also, are there any GSIs currently and, if so, what are the GSIPK and GSISK?